# Create new figure automatically for matplotlib plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am using matplotlib and seaborn to create my plots within a PDF file that collects all open figures.

In a simplified form my code looks as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages


# create random dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(30, 4), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

# create plots
ax1 = sns.lineplot(data=df.loc[:, ['A']], color='r')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2 = sns.lineplot(data=df.loc[:, ['B']], color='b', ax=ax2)

# this works in order to separate the plots into different figures
# but I do not want to call plt.figure() before every plot
#plt.figure()
ax3 = sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='C', y='D')

# create pdf file with plots
pp = PdfPages('plots.pdf')

figs = [plt.figure(n) for n in plt.get_fignums()]
for fig in figs:
    fig.savefig(pp, format='pdf')
pp.close()

# close all existing figures
for fig in figs:
    plt.close(fig)
```

But this way, the figures are plotted into one page within the PDF file because they belong to the same figure:

[image]

I can create a new figure manually for every plot using `plt.figure()`.

But how can I automatically create plots in a new figure or at least put all plots on different figures when creating the PDF file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you are saving all figures into the same pdf here:

```
pp = PdfPages('plots.pdf')
[...]
for fig in figs:
    fig.savefig(pp, format='pdf')
```

try to dynamically change the pdf's name, this way you will have a new file for every figure

Comment: Actually, I want them to be all in one pdf document.